# Is it possible to add the content of a cell into a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, reference, cell, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to import some values from a JSON file but they keep adding things to the list and it's a big no-no for me (it has 2,000 rows of items already). I didn't see any information about this, and I don't understand the INDIRECT or ADDRESS functions.

Can anyone explain it a bit?

An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoObk.png) of what I'm doing.

I'm using Google Sheets not Excel and Sheets doesn't like unfinished formulae so when I try to concatenate the formula it adds the end brackets on mid formula!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a formula if you are attempting to concatenate strings in Excel.

What I do is put everything before the text to be inserted:

`import("api.kitchen.utility/`

into a cell, say E1,  then the following text in E2:

`"; "noheader,notruncate")`

Assuming the text you want to include is in A1 - A??.

In B1 put the following formula:
`=$CONCAT($E$1, $A1, $E$2)`
Copy B1 and paste down to rest of range.

$E$1 means the pointer will always point to Cell E1 no matter what.  The $A1 means the column will always will be 'A' but the row will increment when it is increased due to copy or fill.

A bare reference G10 (in H10) when pasted or filled always refers the the cell to the immediate right.

In other words add a $ to a row, column, or both to always point to the same row, column or cell.